# streaming api disconnecting

Tags: api, soap-api, streaming-api

Can anyone point me out why i am getting this error. 
Much help is appreciated.

```
IN >>>> {"advice":{"interval":0,"reconnect":"handshake"},"channel":"/meta/connect","id":"71","error":"403::Unknown client","successful":false}
OUT >>> {"channel":"/meta/handshake","version":"1.0","supportedConnectionTypes":["in-process","websocket","long-polling"],"id":"72"}
IN >>>> {"ext":{"sfdc":{"failureReason":"401::Authentication invalid"},"replay":true,"payload.format":true},"advice":{"reconnect":"none"},"channel":"/meta/handshake","id":"72","error":"403::Handshake denied","successful":false}
```

Thanks,
Darko

Answer (score 0):

Handshake failures might be due to certification mismatch between your org and the endpoint that you are hitting